# Speed of unmixing between polar and nonpolar solvent

Tags: solvents

I have put water and silicone oil (viscosity 100 cSt) together into a jar. Then I colored the water blue to make identifying the interfaces easier. When I shake it heavily, a kind of silicone+water "foam" builds up, which only unmixes very slowly. Even when I only shake it slightly (as for the image below), so that a few major bubbles of water enter the silicone, the bubbles won't pop back into the bulk of water for ages.

[image]

I think I remember, from doing chemistry in the past (I am not a chemist), a mixture of chloroform and water unmixes very fast, while a mixture of water and kerosene did not (i.e. performed like my recent silicone oil experiment). I first thought a lack of difference in density (because the silicone seems pretty close to 1 g/cm^3) hinders unmixing, but while chloroform has indeed much higher density than water, kerosene also has significantly lower density than water. So I think it must be something else than density. But it can't be surface tension either, can it. Because nonpolar solvents always have lower surface tension than water (lack of hydrogen bonding), don't they.

So what makes one pair of polar/nonpolar solvent unmix fast while the other builds up foam? I think that must be very important for a chemist during washing after synthesis, but I can't seem to find a suitable search term.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0920410521016521

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion

Comment: @Mithoron: unfortunately I can't read the science direct article due to the paywall. But the contained keyword "demulsification" led me to this article which I found helpful: https://petrowiki.spe.org/Oil_demulsification

Comment: So my preliminary explanation for my problem child is threefold: 1) small density difference between the two solvents keeps the droplets from coming close to each other due to gravity, 2) once the (water) droplets have come close enough, further approaching is inhibited by still comparatively high viscosity (of the silicone oil) 3) internal surfactant effects of the silicone keeps the droplets from coalescing.

Comment: In an inspiration that the surfactant effects of silicone oil might come from the "etherlike" siloxane groups which pair with the hydrogen atoms of water to form hydrogen bonds, I put acetone into the mixture, in the hopes that its molecules would straddle inbetween water and siloxane groups and so weaken the surfactant action. And indeed, the interliquid "foam" resolved *much* faster then (estimated factor 100). Only disadvantage is, the water fraction has become a little blurry now (where it was rather clear before), possibly because some of the silicone got emulsified into it now.